# Add multiselect crm field in SSRS data set

Tags: dataset, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

I am importing all the fields form CRM to SSRS, to create a dynamic SSRS report. I have a multiselect field in CRM, when I try to add this multiselect field in SSRS DataSet, it is throwing me an error saying that multisite select cannot be added to SSRS. can someone help me in fixing this. Field - SelectCourse-> which contains list of course. Depending on the selected course i should show the report. I don't think parameter is necessary in this.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/265188

Comment: can you successfully connect to your crm db? If so; can you select one specific field? Perhaps provide a code snipt of your select statement? like select [field_1] from Crm.table_sxy.

Comment: you worse case will be to ETL; using ssis that table into a persisted db outside of the Crm world. be successfully able to connect to that db. and then re-try.